# AT command, send sms with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sms, at-command

I'm trying to send an sms from Qt trough serial port on a GPRS modem.
Does anyone experienced that?

I'm able to connect to the modem, but don't know which AT command to send and how to get the response back from the modem.

(Here I'm making a phone call; easier)

```
QSerialPort serial;
serial.setPortName(name);
serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

if (serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable())
{

output = "ATD + +32111111111;\r\n";
serial.write(output);
serial.flush();

// Doesn't work:
//input = serial.readAll();
//qDebug() << input;

output = "\r\n";
serial.write(output);
serial.flush();

Sleep.sleep(30);

serial.close();

}

else
{

}
```

Maybe end signal `\r\n` is not good or needs a Special AT command to start?

Comment: Even the smallest of googling [would have suggested](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgs-text-mode/): `AT+CMGS="<NUMBER>"<CR>Message<CTRL-Z>`. If you're having I/O issues then that's something else.

Comment: I managed to read the answer of the modem with :  
`serial.waitForReadyRead(200);  
input = serial.readAll();  
qDebug() << input;`

Could you please write me an example, because I don't know the meaning of '<CTRL-Z>'...  
I'm sorry, but I'm a begginer. I've found this information on Google, but don't know how to properly use it in Qt...

Comment: Ctrl-Z is the actual ascii code `26` i.e. you write that specific character following the writing of the message.

Comment: Here "\x1A" works also... I'll give it a try with "26". Thank you

Comment: Yes, your use of `"x1a"` corresponds to the correct character in that case (26 is 0x1A in hex)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to get it work, but still not sure off great syntax of phone and message.
Any idea?

```
// initialize the modem
QSerialPort serial;
serial.setPortName(name);
serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

if (serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable())
{
// Text message mode
output = "AT+CMGF=1\r\n";
serial.write(output);
serial.flush();

// read the response of the modem
serial.waitForReadyRead(200);
input = serial.readAll();
qDebug() << input;

// set phone number and Message
output = "AT+CMGS=\"+321111111\"\r\ Hello World! \x1A/r/n";
serial.write(output);
serial.flush();

// get reponse
serial.waitForReadyRead(200);
input = serial.readAll();
qDebug() << input;

// close the communication
serial.close();

}

else
{
qDebug() << "You have a problem";
}
```